# Can a selection sort algorithm terminate from its loop early the way a bubble sort is able to?

Tags: c, flags, selection-sort

This program will run fine if I do not include the early termination flag, but it only needs 10 sort passes to fully sort the list, not the full 12. However, when  the termination flag is included, it terminates the sorting too early. Following the logic, I can see that this happens because after the third pass the array is ordered like this:
[image]

with the index i currently at 7, there are no lesser values to swap it with, so the flag does not get a value of 1 assigned to it and the loop terminates. So I guess my question is, is it possible to break out of a selection sort algorithm early and still fully complete the sort?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
     int list[13]= {23,8,4,7,22,18,39,42,5,88,16,11,3};
     int temp,min,flag;
     printf( "Before Sorting\n" );
     printf( "23 8 4 7 22 18 39 42 5 88 16 11 3\n" );

for( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
    {
        flag = 0;
        min = i;

        for( int j=i+1; j<13; j++ )
            {
                if( list[j]<list[min] )
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                        min = j  ;
                    }
            }

        if( !flag )
            break;

        temp = list[i];
        list[i]=list[min];
        list[min]=temp;

        printf( "\nAfter Pass %d.\n",i+1 );
        for( int i=0; i<13; i++ )
            printf( "%d ",list[i] );

        printf( "\n" );
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't break out like this. Here, the current value, 7, is the lowest in the list, so it does (should) not swap with anything, but that doesn't say anything about the remaining file (except that all values are known to be >= 7).

Comment: Rather than try to optimize selection sort, you could look to smarter sorting algorithms with better time complexity.

Comment: The only thing that you can skip, in a selection sort, is the swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed you can. Here is such an implementation,

```
int selsort(int v[], int n){

  bool sorted = false; // v not known to be sorted
  int  i = 0;          // i smallest elements in place 

  while(!sorted){
    // find min v[i..n-1]
    // check if v[i..n-1] is sorted

    int  j   = i+1;
    int  min = i;    // position of minimum of v[i..j-1]
    sorted   = true; // v[i..j-1] sorted

    while(j<n){
      if(v[j]<v[min]) min = j;        // update min
      if(v[j]<v[j-1]) sorted = false; // update sorted
      j++;
    }

    if (!sorted){
      // place min v[i..n-1] in v[i]
      int aux = v[i];
      v[i]    = v[min];
      v[min]  = aux;      

      i++;
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As usual, in iteration `i` we start with `v[0..i-1]` sorted with the `i` smallest elements of the array in the correct place. So we want to find the `min v[i..n-1]` to put in position `i`. In this variant, as we do that we also check if `v[i..n-1]` is sorted. If it is sorted then there is nothing else to do.

**Your implementation**

In your implementation, the way you test for an ordered segment is wrong.

```
if( list[j]<list[min] )
    {
        flag = 1;
        min = j  ;
    }
```

Your flag will stay at `0` as long as you don't have to update the minimum in the inner loop. So any segment with the minimum in the first position will be considered sorted.

Answer (score 2):

There are almost no redeeming qualities in bubble sort, the nicest thing about it is its name. Donald Knuth has said that

> the bubble sort seems to have nothing to recommend it, except a catchy name and the fact that it leads to some interesting theoretical problems

And indeed, from Wikipedia about [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort):

> Among simple average-case Θ(n²) algorithms, selection sort almost always outperforms bubble sort and gnome sort.

There is no variation in selection sort - its running time does not depend on the ordering. For another good simple O(n²) algorithm that has variable running time, see [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to break early in a selection sort, just like in a bubble sort. This can be done by comparing the order of all adjacent elements during an iteration.

However, this rarely helps in practice because this comparison happens on unsorted data. So an early exit is just an unlikely lucky break.

The key advantage of insertion sort, being also O(n^2), is that the break happens on the already sorted data. Thus there's a high chance to reduce effort, especially when the input data is partially pre-sorted.